# Cakephp 2.4 Ajax Login

Tags: php, jquery, cakephp, cakephp-2.4

Not sure which part went wrong and tried to search through google for tutorial but no luck with the source out there. Basically whenever I try to submit the form, it check through chrome network and does the redirection to google.com even though the password is wrong. Anyone has clearer understand on cakephp auth to guide me through?

Here is what I did

**AppController.php**

```
public $components = array('DebugKit.Toolbar',
                           'Session',
                           'Auth');
```

**UsersController.php**

```
public function login()
{
    if ($this->request->is('post')) 
    {
        $this->request->data['User']['username'] = $_POST['email'];
        $this->request->data['User']['password'] = $_POST['password'];

        if ($this->Auth->login()) 
        {
            $this->redirect('http://www.google.com');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `$_POST['email']` => That should be `$this->request->data['email']`. But it would be cleaner to post the correct fields right away - or make yourself a custom Auth adapter here to process those ajax fields instead of mapping them around.

Comment: Hi mark, $_POST['email'] and $this->request->data['email'] both should work the same no?

Comment: A lot of things work the same, there is still a preferred framework-approach on this :) I was merely pointing that out.

Comment: If it's getting through and redirecting to Google with the wrong password, there's an issue.  Are you sure the user doesn't exist?  If you debug `$this->Auth->user()` within the if login area, what user does it show? ...etc

Comment: I don't think your POST password is salted or md5'd either (default functionality for Cake Auth).

Comment: Used this simple hash password provided by Cakephp http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html on user model before save. Amazingly auth login applied the same hashing password afterward :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out the reason redirecting keeps going through is that the previous user already logged in successfully. So what I do is providing the logout link and try again.

```
public function logout() {
   return $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
}
```

Thanks again everyone.